# is the lexicographic order topology on the unit square connected/path connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was wondering, given the lexicographic order topology on $S=[0,1] \times [0,1]$, is it connected (and path connected)?

I found a reference to [Steen's and Seebach's Counterexamples in Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048668735X), and in page 73 they say that:

> Since in the linear order on $S$ there are no consecutive points, and since every (bounded) subset of $S$ has a least upper bound, $S$ is connected.

But I don't know what a consecutive point is? (perhaps there is another name for this type of point)
 And I dont see how this implies that $S$ is connected?

And my second question is - is $S$ path connected? According to the book it isn't, but I don't see exactly how.

Comment: The statement "on $X$ there are no consective points" is a statement about a pair of points, not about a single point. It means that for each $x,y \in X$ such that $x<y$ there exists $z \in X$ such that $x<y<z$.

Comment: @LeeMosher

So not having consecutive points means that not for every $x,y\in S$ exists such a $z$? And I dont see how does this assist me in showing that there are no two disjoint open sets that cover $S$?

Comment: @LeeMosher: Shouldn't $z$ be between $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: The first refers to the theorem that a linearly ordered space is connected iff it is complete and densely ordered (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_Ordered_Space_is_Connected_iff_Linear_Continuum). Densely ordered means that between any 2 points always strictly lies a third, which means that there are no points $x < y$ such that $(x,y)$ is empty (and such points are called consecutive; $x,y$ is also called a "jump" then.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: yes, $z$ should be between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X$ ($=S$?) is path connected, so there exists a continuous path $\gamma : [a,b] \to X$ such that $\gamma(a)=(0,0)=P$ and $\gamma(b)=(1,1)=Q$. Since every point of $X - \{P,Q\}$ disconnects $P$ from $Q$ it follows that $\gamma$ is surjective. For each $t \in [0,1]$ let $J_t$ be the open vertical segment with lower endpoint at $(t,1/4)$ and with upper endpoint at $(t,3/4)$. The sets $J_t$ are open, nonempty, and pairwise disjoint in $X$. It follows that the sets $\gamma^{-1}(J_t)$ are open, nonempty, and pairwise disjoint in $[a,b]$. But this is impossible, because $[a,b]$ contains a countable dense set.

Almost the same proof shows that the path components of $X$ are precisely the vertical arcs $\{t\} \times [0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by "every point of $X - \{ P , Q \}$ disconnects $P$ from $Q$? And secondly, I don't understand the contradiction, why does $[a,b]$ having a countable dense set contradicts us? And how do we know $[a,b]$ has such a dense set that is countable?

Comment: @Eric_: The set of rational numbers in $[a,b]$ is dense, that is, every open subset of $[a,b]$ contains a rational number. So if you have an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $[a,b]$, such as the sets $\gamma^{-1}(J_t)$, then by picking one rational number out of each of those sets you will get an uncountable set of rational numbers, which is a contradiction.

Comment: :Okay, but just why does "every point of $X- \{ P,Q \}$ disconnects $P$ from $Q$?" Can't this argument work on every path $\gamma$? Or maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: @Eric_: A similar argument works for any path $\gamma$ whose two endpoints are contained in different vertical segments $s \times [0,1]$, $t \times [0,1]$, $s \ne t$, with the conclusion that that the image of that path contains every vertical segment $r \times [0,1]$ with $r$ strictly between $s,t$; and therefore, by the same countability argument, no such path exists. This, in fact, is exactly what I was alluding to in my last paragraph.