# Give an example of a linear continuum which is not the real line $\mathbb{R}$, nor topologically equivalent to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: Give an example of a linear continuum which is not the real line $\mathbb{R}$, nor
topologically equivalent to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.**

**Definition of Linear Continuum:** Let X be a linearly ordered set with order <. We say that X is a linear continuum iff it satisfies the following two axioms:

(1) LUB: X has the least upper bound property.
(2) Betweenness: $\forall x$ < $y$ $\in X$,  $\exists z$ $\in X$, such that  $x < z < y$.

This is how I did it, not sure whether its accurate or not.

I tried to prove that $I$ x $I$ is not connected under subspace topology of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ under dictionary order. Since, ${x}$ X $I$ is open in $I$ X $I$, therefore, for each $x$ $\in$ $I$, say (${a}$ X $[a,b]$) $\cup$ ${y}$ X $I$, where $y \in [a,b]$, we can clearly say that their intersection will be $\emptyset$, i.e. (${a}$ X $[a,b]$) $\cup$ {${y}$ X $I$} = $I X I$, & (${a}$ X $[a,b]$) $\cap$ (${y}$ X $I$) = $\emptyset$. Hence, its not connected under subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but its still a linear continuum.

I was trying to come up with something else but unfortunately I couldn't get a better example. Need help from someone on this. Appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: $\{x\} \times I$ is *not* open: (x,1) is not an interior point if $x<1$ and neither is $(x,0)$ if $x>0$. But the sets $\{x\} \times (0,1)$ are open (but not closed, so connectedness is not in danger, and in fact $I \times I$ *is* connected.

Answer (score 1):

$I\times I$ is clearly (path)connected under subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You incorrectly claim that $\{x\}\times I$ is open in $I\times I$, it is not.

Unless you mean that you consider $I\times I$ with the topology induced by the dictionary order. However even under dictionary topology $\{x\}\times I$ is not open. And in fact $I\times I$ is connected, although not path connected, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980647/is-the-lexicographic-order-topology-on-the-unit-square-connected-path-connected). Therefore $I\times I$ cannot be homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ connectedness and path connectedness coincide.

For a different example you can consider any well ordered set $\omega$ which is big enough, i.e. its cardinality is strictly greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$. Then you take $\omega\times [0,1)$ with the dictionary order. This space is a linear continuum and cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ regardless of topology, simply because it is bigger than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ is already enough.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, but "why?" question requires more difficult explanation in the $\omega_1$ case.

Comment: just non-ccc will do. And maybe the OP doesn’t know ordinale large enough actually exist (Munkres’ coverage doesn’t not include such things).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma hopefully every mathematician passed some basic set theory course and knows that every set can be well ordered (under the axiom of choice) and that there are sets of bigger cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$. I wouldn't call that a difficult knowledge. Also, not sure why you mention Munkres? I don't see op refering to the book.

Comment: I recognise the exercise from it, plus linear continuum is a term he uses, in that definition.He treats only a little bit of the theory you mention so it’s not assumed for his readers.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the lexicographically ordered square $I \times I$ is a classic example of a linear continuum, even compact, that is not a subspace of the reals, e.g. because it is not separable (and all subspaces of $\Bbb R$ are second countable hence separable). This can be seen as all subsets of the form $\{x\} \times (0,1)$ are open, and pairwise disjoint so any dense set must intersect all of them, and each time in a new point, so all dense sets are at least size continuum too. If $X$ has the property that all pairwise disjoint families of non-empty open sets are countable, it’s said to be a ccc space (ccc stands for countable chain condition, which is an historically grown term). So this square is not ccc, hence non-separable.

Another classic example is based on $\omega_1$ (or $\Omega$, as Munkres calls it) the smallest uncountable well-ordered set. If we order $\omega_1 \times [0,1)$ lexicographically we get another linear continuum (the *long line*)( being a linear continuum already follows from the well-orderedness of the first space) that is not a subspace of the reals for the same reason (non-separable), even though it is even path-connected, unlike the lexicographically ordered square. It also is non-ccc.

In fact all separable linear continua can be embedded as subspaces of $\Bbb R$ and all known other examples  of non-separable ones are also not ccc. It has long been an open problem whether a non-separable but ccc linear continuum exists and it turned out that in **some** models of set theory such so-called *Suslin lines* do exist and in **other** models they do not. So you cannot just construct an example of one of those (although they are intriguing objects when they do exist).

Answer (score 0):

A ready example that comes to my mind from prior interests of mine and that is fairly natural, in that it is not specifically contrived for this purpose, I'd say, is the **Dedekind completion of a suitably large non-Archimedean ordered field.**

Non-Archimedean ordered fields can be made of any cardinality one desires: to do this, it simply suffices to truncate the construction process for Conway's *surreal numbers* "just before" a suitably large "birthday", where "just before" means to take the union of all the preceding steps but not including the step with that birthday. The cardinality of this set will be at least as (may be equal to; I don't know this part) large as that of the ordinal labelling the birthday, and if that ordinal is large enough, one can guarantee it is a field; in particular, any uncountable ordinal will work and so one can use the initial ordinal of a cardinal larger than the real continuum; then take the Dedekind completion: by inclusion, it must also surpass the real continuum in cardinality, and it will be a linear (general) continuum, but algebraically a rather bad structure. As the cardinality surpasses that of $\mathbb{R}$, topologically this cannot be homeomorphic thereto.

---

ADD: in fact, you don't need to worry so much about the field property since this is a purely topological matter and so it simply suffices to just say to take the stage set $S_\alpha$ of all surreals with birthday up to and including $\alpha$ an uncountable ordinal larger than the initial ordinal of the continuum, e.g. $\alpha = \mathrm{init}(\beth_2)$, and then Dedekind-complete it, i.e. form $\mathrm{DC}(S_\alpha)$. It will be compact (surreals "equivalent" to $\pm \alpha$ will bookend it), but also fail the homeomorphism properties regardless.